# fancyapp iFrame does not close in IE 8, 9, or 10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox

I've implemented Fancyapps 2.1.5. I can get the iFrame to open and close in Mac OS 10.8: Safari, FireFox, Chrome, and Windows 7:  FireFox, and Chrome. However, it will not close when I click the X button on IE 8, 9, or 10. Does anyone know what I need to do to make sure the iFrame closes in IE?

I've read a few posts about using the correct DOCTYPE, but that doesn't seem to help. I'm using this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Fancyapp's demo's use simply  - that doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Comment: I think it's a css issue with global css rules, perhaps. Can you share a link to the demo page with the issue?

Comment: The odd thing is the code all works on IE when it's on our test Apache server. However, when we load the code onto the production server at pointinspace.com it doesn't work. We had to remove the code from the live site because it needed to go live, so we chose another method. I still want to know why it won't work if I want to use it on other projects.

Comment: most likely it was a path issue of the fancybox files